# How to make php generate random numbers untill the specific number is reached

Tags: php

I want a random integer to be generated in the range from 1 to 3 until 2 will be generated.

Please review the code below - What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
<?php
    $min = 1;
    $max = 3;
    $number = rand($min,$max);
    while($number !== 2) {
    echo ($number);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `rand()` is not in the while loop, so the `rand()` will execute one time.

If the `$number` is not 2, the while loop will execute without stoping.

If the $number is 2, the while loop will not executed.

```
while(($number = rand($min, $max)) != 2){echo $number;}
```

Comment: so i just ran this forgetting to set a min and max :)